# Store a cell value as a variable

Tags: vba, excel

Depending on the values in a statement i would like to place a values in a cell. 
However because I need to reuse this statement I would to create a cell destination
as a variable so I can easily change this.

I produced the following code but this does not seem to work. Any thoughts?

```
dim test_number as Integer
test_number = 3

    'This value could be changed
rel_cell = Sheets("risk_cat_2").Cells(4, 6)

If test_number >= 3 Then
            rel_cell = "Category 1"
Elseif test_number >= 3 Then
            rel_cell = "Category 2"
```

Comment: For starters, your "If" and "Elseif" tests are the same (test_number >= 3), so "Category 2" would never be reached

Comment: `Dim rel_cell As Range` then `Set rel_cell = Sheets("risk_cat_2").Cells(4, 6)`

Answer (score 0):

The following adjustments to your code should fix it.  The strings must be passed to the Value of the `rel_cell` which is also a Range, given the way you chose to allocate the location first.  This also requires the Set statement for the Range

```
dim test_number as Integer, rel_cell As Range
test_number = 3

'This value could be changed
Set rel_cell = Sheets("risk_cat_2").Cells(4, 6)

If test_number >= 3 Then
        rel_cell.Value = "Category 1"
Else
        rel_cell.Value = "Category 2"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understood the question correctly as the above answer seems to go a different route. Yet, whenever I hear "reuse" in the context of coding I immediately think of pushing code into a separate function or sub. Then you can easily reuse this code.

In your case this would mean something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub tmpTest()

Dim rel_cell As String
Dim test_number As Integer

test_number = 3

Call EvaluateIt(test_number, Sheets("risk_cat_2").Cells(4, 6))

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub EvaluateIt(test_number As Integer, cell As Range)

Dim rel_cell As String

Select Case test_number
    Case Is >= 3
        rel_cell = "Category 1"
    Case Is >= 0
        rel_cell = "Category 2"
    Case Is < 0
        'some other category
    Case Else
        rel_cell = "(unknown)"
End Select

cell.Value2 = rel_cell

End Sub
```

The other think I (personally) try to avoid are multiple `ElseIf`. The `case` method has been created just for that purpose and is (to me) much more legible. So, I changed that part in your code too (for your consideration).